# Best practice to implement login mechanism on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'd like to ask for advice about what is the best practice to implement a communication mechanism for an Apple Watch app to make sure the user has logged in on the iPhone app.

My Watch app is paired with the corresponding iPhone app. The iPhone app needs to be logged in in order for the Watch app to be used (to display info, etc.) The login mechanism on the iPhone has already been implemented and it is working perfectly. The Watch app needs to ask the corresponding iPhone app if the user has logged in. If so, it will return a code, and in turn the Watch can display data or query the server (with the login credentials) for more data. If the user has not logged in on iPhone, the Watch app will display a button asking the user to login on the iPhone app.

I've checked out Apple's doc and I think WCSession's 
- sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler on the Watch and its corresponding WCSessionDelegate's - session:didReceiveMessage on iOS seems to be way to go.

Any advice, or better ways to implement such functionality/logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WCSession's sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler is indeed a good way to go about getting data from the iPhone on demand. Since you need to ask the iPhone when the user is doing an action on the watch, I would go with this method.

You may also consider using handoff from the Apple Watch to the iPhone so your user goes right to the screen on the phone you want them to login on.